# Преобразование рекурсивного метода в итерацию

Tags: java, рекурсия, производительность

Не раз уже слышал, что итерация - всегда производительнее, чем рекурсия, а также о том, что они взаимозаменяемы. Есть ли возможность как-то преобразовать этот код в итеративный, а главное - даст ли это прирост производительности?

```
public static int calculate(Foo f){
    int hash = 0;
    t = f.getType();
    hash += t;
    switch (t) {
        case 1:
            FooMap fm = (FooMap) f;

            Set<String> keys = fm.keys();

            for (String name : keys)
                hash += name.hashCode() ^ calculate(fm.getValue(name));

            return hash;
        case 2:
            return hash + f.hashCode();
        default:
            return hash;
    }
}
```

Pss: FooMap#getValue в данном случае возвращает Foo, то есть в объекте могут находиться вложенные элементы (как в Json), что, собственно, и делает на вид преобразование кода в итеративный невозможным. Сам по себе метод очень часто вызывается, по этому даже если разница во времени очень важна.

Если данный пример можно преобразовать в итеративный вариант - пожалуйста, подскажите как. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: если метод часто вызывается, наверное, имеет смысл его результаты кешировать? А так без замеров на конкретных данных сложно сказать, будет ли какой прирост производительности.

Comment: К сожалению, проблема заключается в том, что кеширование невозможно. В метод постоянно передаются разные инстанции класса, и они практически никогда не совпадают. Если говорить о частоте вызова подобного метода - не менее десятка раз в секунду

Comment: Что вам мешает сделать локальную переменную, которая будет хранить `Foo` и просто записывать туда новый его вариант и считать?

Comment: Как я уже сказал - Foo может быть вложенным. В случае типа '1' - нужно посчитать несколько раз, притом вполне вероятно, что в 1 из подзначений будет тоже тип '1'

Comment: Плюс tym32167 говорит про кеширования результата `calculate` в `Foo`

Comment: В моём случае класс Foo - это класс из внешней библиотеки, по этому я не могу воспользоваться таким подходом.

Comment: Тогда тут будет уместен вариант алгоритма в глубину с стеком, где будут храниться текущий родитель `Foo`. Т.е. досчитывать строки с циклом придется как только вы пройдете всех детей. Но это страшно будет смотреться по сравнению с рекурсией. Вызов метода не такой страшный вариант. Но если у вас теоретически может быть превышение количества, то придется переписать. Я бы написал, но не за компьютером

Comment: ну а глубина дерева инстансов у вас какая? Насколько глубоко у вас рекурсия уходит?

Comment: Преобразовать можно. Прироста производительности не будет или будет совсем небольшой. Обратите внимание на код с циклом: вы строите копию множества ключей и отыскиваете каждый ключ заново. Оба пункта медленные. Стандартная библиотека ускоряет их с помощью [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).

Comment: Глубина может быть разной, но в среднем достигает 5. Касаемо Map.Entry - опять же, упираюсь в то, что FooMap - класс из внешней библиотеки :(.